# Leverage parallelism for producing Ordered Windowed Aggregations (i.e., Top 10 query)

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to leverage parallelism to speed up a Top-10 window operation. My application consists of events that have a timestamp and a key and (i.e., `Tuple2<Long,String>`) and my goal is to produce the Top-10 most frequent keys for tumbling windows of 30 minutes(using event-time). To this end, my query consists of an ingress, a window, and an aggregation stage. In other words, my code will need to do something like the following:

```
DataStream<Tuple3<Long, String, Integer>> s = env
    .readTextFile("data.csv")
    .map(new MapFunction<String, Tuple3<Long, String, Integer>>() {
      @Override
      public Tuple3<Long, String, Integer> map(String s) throws Exception {
        String[] tokens = s.split(",");
        return new Tuple3<Long, String, Integer>(Long.parseLong(tokens[0]),
            tokens[1], 1);
      }})
    .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
        new AscendingTimestampExtractor<Tuple3<Long, String, Integer>>() {
          @Override
          public long extractAscendingTimestamp(Tuple3<Long, String, Integer> t) {
            return t.f0;
          }}).setParallelism(1);
```

The above is the code to parse data from a CSV file and assign event time (i.e., Ingress). The reason that I set parallelism to 1 is because I need the events to appear ordered so that I can assign them to windows.

The tricky part comes next, in which I try to make speed up execution while producing correct (and ordered) window results.

**Naive (Serial) Execution**

The following code presents a solution that does not make use of any parallelism and produces a serial stream:

```
DataStream<Tuple2<Long, String>> windowedTopTen = s
        .windowAll(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(30)))
        .apply(new SerialAggregation()).setParallelism(1);
```

where `SerialAggregation` extends `RichAllWindowFunction<Tuple3<Long, String, Integer>, Tuple2<Long, String>, TimeWindow>` and for each tumbling window a `Tuple2<Long, String>` (`Long` is the timestamp and `String` contains the top 10 keys).

The naive approach produces the correct result and the resulting data stream is ordered with ascending timestamps. Unfortunately, it does not leverage multi-threading and as a result when the input data are some GBs, the execution takes a while to complete.

**Parallel (Faster) Approach**

After looking into Flink's documentation on windows, I am trying to come up with a smarter way for implementing the Top 10 example by using `parallelism > 1` and at the same time produce the correct result for each window. Therefore, I see that I need to transform `s` to a `KeyedStream` and then apply a `window()` transformation. In essence:

```
DataStream<Tuple2<Long, String>> windowedTopTen = s
    .keyBy(1)
    .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(30)))
    .apply(new PartialAggregation()).setParallelism(N);
```

Where `PartialAggregation()` would produce partial results (of disjoint key sets) for different timestamps. In other words, my understanding is that for the same timestamp `t1` I will end up with `partial_result_1` to `partial_result_N` where `N` is the parallelism that I have set. My goal is to aggregate all partial results for a particular timestamp (like `t1`), but I do not know how to do that. Also, when I am able to combine partial results with matching timestamps, how will I be able to produce a datastream, whose tuples are ordered based on the timestamps (like the result that the Naive Solution produces).

**Questions**

1. How can I complete the **Parallel (Faster) approach** to produce the desired result and combine partial results with matching timestamps?
2. After I combine partial results for each timestamp, is there a way to produce a data stream in which results appear ordered based on timestamps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's going to be easier to combine the partial top 10 results into the overall top 10 if you replace your Tuple2 with a Tuple3 where the String is a single key, and the Integer is the counter.

Then you can tack on a second layer of windowing using windowAll and an aggregating window function that keeps the top 10 keys (overall), and their counts.

Comment: thanks. During the weekend I came up with (pretty much) what you suggested: After the partial result parallel evaluation, I define a `windowAll()` followed by a `appy()` to combine all partial results and come up with the top-10 set. In addition, I extended my code to contain an additional `Integer` field for the count. However, I have a more important problem: Among consecutive runs, I don't get reproducible results. In detail, I don't get the same number of windows among different results. That should not happen since my data are stored in a file and I use `EventTime`.

Comment: When using EventTime on a finite, historic stream you need to take care that your watermarking makes sense. If you are using autowatermarking then Flink will try to generate a watermark every 200msec, but your program might sometimes run to completion before running for 200 msec. And you also need to take care that you provide a watermark that closes the last window.

Comment: Thank you very much again! As you can see on the source code, I have been using the `AscendingTimestampExtractor`, which seems to be able to make sense for my use-case. I resolved the problem regarding non-reproducible results by setting parallelism to 1 (for all transformations up to `assignTimestampsAndWatermarks()`). However, that takes me back to serial execution for my partial results, since they are handled by only 1 mapper (output states Mapper (1/1)). If I am understanding Flink correctly, it's hard to deterministically process historical streams while utilizing parallelism. right?

Comment: Update on my comment above, I was wrong. Flink spawns multiple mappers for the partial result. I was just reading older log files. Again, thank you @alpinegizmo for your answers and comments.